# Selenium - multiple tags

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am writing a script for a friend to automate her workflow a little bit and I am using selenium with python. 
On a website, I have a radiobutton section which looks like this :

```
<br/>
<input id="orgtype" name="orgtype" value="euk" onclick="setvalue('orgtype','euk'); setvalue('Dcut-noTM',Dcut_noTM()); setvalue('Dcut-TM',Dcut_TM());" checked="" type="radio"/>
  Eukaryotes
<br/>
<input id="orgtype" name="orgtype" value="gram-" onclick="setvalue('orgtype','gram-'); setvalue('Dcut-noTM',Dcut_noTM()); setvalue('Dcut-TM',Dcut_TM());" type="radio"/>
  Gram-negative bacteria
<br/>
<input id="orgtype" name="orgtype" value="gram+" onclick="setvalue('orgtype','gram+'); setvalue('Dcut-noTM',Dcut_noTM()); setvalue('Dcut-TM',Dcut_TM());" type="radio"/>
  Gram-positive bacteria
<br/>
```

I am trying to select the middle option which has a value of "gram-". I was wondering if anyone could help me with  ( or pointing to a very simple tutorial on how to ) finding the right element by xpath? overall I know you can write ( for example :

```
user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#email')
```

but I am not sure on how to go about finding elements with multiple tags.

Thank you :)

Comment: `user = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="gram-"]')`, should work

Comment: @Stack it works! Thank you! Just out of curiosity ( and future endeavours) , how would you use the "input" and the "value"?

Comment: You can use chrome inspect tab to check the xpath , and here is a good source to learn XPATH https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiGhO3Kv-3UAhVMQI8KHXZUBHIQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fxml%2Fxpath_intro.asp&usg=AFQjCNHGRgECp0CzHZKTCy9IqPAnrgOEcA . pretty simple

Comment: @theMicroGirl could you mark on answer as correct to close of the question (as discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253048/4161937)) :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick Solution:

Use `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='gram-']")`.
Explanation:

`//` - select element anywhere in the document starting from the current node (the root of the document).

`//input` - select all input elements anywhere in the document.

`[@value='gram-']` - select element where `value` ist set to `gram-`.

`//input[@value='gram-']` - select every `input` element anywhere in the document with `value="gram-"`.

#### XPath Tutorials:

[XPath Tutorial on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

[XPath Syntax Overview](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 1):

As @Stack said in the comments, you should use *find_element_by_xpath*. If you are unsure as to how to write an xpath, Chrome has a handy option to show the XPath of a selected element. If you open the Developer Tools (Ctrl + Shift + I) and locate the element in the source, you can right click, Copy, Copy XPath.

This is just a quick fix. You should consider learning how XPath works.

Comment: Do keep in mind that the XPath Chrome generates is far from ideal and is not necessarily unique!

Comment: I created a demo site based on the HTML the asker provided and Chrome generated this XPath `//*[@id="orgtype"]` which is not directly referring to the object I selected and also way to generic (selects *every* element with `id="orgtype"`, and we have 3 of them). I know that IDs _should_ be unique, but as we can see, they are not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

By `css` selector:

```
#orgtype[value='gram-']
```

Or by xPath

```
//input[@value= 'gram-']
```

To find by text containing`Gram-negative`:

```
//text()[contains(.,'Gram-negative')]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```